# Customer grid "last logged in" column not showing online users

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account

In the customer grid, which is accessable through the main menu point `Customers` I have a user that has a blank `last logged in` column. When I look in the details off that user by clicking the `edit` link in the row I can clearly see, that the user has logged in AND is still online.

### How can I show the last logged in date of online users in the grid?

[image: Detail view]
[image: filtered grid]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow following step:

1. Create Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <column name="last_login_at">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Last Logged In</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1000</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

2. Create Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="customer_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <virtualType name="Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">customer_grid_flat</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

3. Create Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Grid/Collection.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult;

class Collection extends SearchResult
{
    /**
     * Init collection select
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();
        $this->getSelect()->join(
            ['customer_log' => $this->getTable('customer_log')],
            'customer_log.customer_id = main_table.entity_id',
            ['last_login_at']
        );
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Clear cache.

Comment: what magento module am I overriding here? I don't really want to create my own view.

Comment: At least you need to create your own module, then follow step.

Comment: Here Vendor = your custom vendor name and Module = Your custom module name

Comment: thank you. it worked. I also added `<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>` to keep a consistent formatting

Comment: This solution will filters [exclude] the customers which haven't logged in into the site.

Comment: Need to change date format and timezone, is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$this->getSelect()->joinLeft(` instant of `$this->getSelect()->join(`, This way you could show all the customers. Otherwise it will show only customers who have logged in before.

Answer (score 0):

**@sohel-rana** answer works. However, I will suggest some adjusts:

1. In my **customer_listing.xml** to display the value and the filter as a date, I add the class **Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date** that filter type **dateRange** and the dataType **date**, also the component **Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date**. The final file looks like this:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
>   <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
>     <column name="last_login_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
>       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
>         <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
>           <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
>           <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
>           <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Last Logged In</item>
>           <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
>           <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
>           <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
>         </item>
>       </argument>
>     </column>
>   </columns>
> </listing>
> ```

2. If you have another extension or module that adds additional fields to grid select (for example the Mgento B2B Module) you could have some issues to display that additional data. But I fixed it in my **Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Grid/Collection.php** changed the extends to **\Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection** Additional, to display customer that doesn't have any last login, I changed the **join** to **joinLeft**

> ```
> <?php
> namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Grid;
>
> class Collection extends \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection
> {
>   /**
>    * Init collection select
>    *
>    * @return $this
>    */
>   protected function _initSelect(){
>     parent::_initSelect();
>     $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
>       ['customer_log' => $this->getTable('customer_log')],
>       'customer_log.customer_id = main_table.entity_id',
>       ['last_login_at']
>     );
>     return $this;
>   }
> }
> ?>
> ```